# Podcast on History and evolution of Musics

Tags: classical-music, history

I am looking for a beginner-friendly podcast which can introduce me to the world of music, like beginning from the old times and through the classic era and last century to the present. Do you know of any podcasts on [History of Music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_music)?

[Philosophize This!](http://philosophizethis.org/) podcast helps me a lot to understand Philosophy from scratch. It requires no prior knowledge and understandable to the public. To be clear, I am looking for something similar on the history and evolution of Music.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you're open to something paid instead of free, but Professor Greenberg's [How to Listen To, and Understand, Great Music](https://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/how-to-listen-to-and-understand-great-music-3rd-edition.html) is not only the de-facto standard among the musicians I know, it is also simply the best set of lectures I have ever listened to on any topic.

He takes you from very early music history, about which very little is known, and slowly works his way to the turn of the 20th century. There's a *lot* in there, but Greenberg keeps it funny, keeps it interesting, and keeps it moving.  He's one of the preeminent scholars on music history, and it shows.